# Merge two directories with large content on slow storage efficiently

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sh

I have two directory structures on a USB drive that have various files that are the same, and each have files that the other one doesn't.

What I want to do is to move over directory structure B to A. It is ok that B's content is gone after the merge. Directories in A must not be erased, because otherwise I lose A's content. The mv command won't work I think, because it will complain that it can't move a directory because a destination directory in the same place is not empty. mv B/* A/ won't work either because some sub directory will also not be empty.
cp -a B/* A/ is bad (even with -u), because it will take way too long, because the files are on a USB drive, and there possibly too many of them, making the drive run out of capacity.
rsync has the same problem, because it doesn't appear to have a move/rename feature, and it can only move files by copying them.

So either, I'm going to have to write a script that will recursively run through B, and create missing directories and move missing files to A.
But I'm hoping that there is a command or option or utility that I don't know about.

Comment: I am assuming that you want to copy only the directory structure from B and not the files in B. 'find B/ -type d' will give you a list of the directories under B. 'mkdir -p' will create parent directories if they do not exist. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe `cpio` has the capabilities you are wanting. This command:

```
cd B
find . -type f -print0 | cpio -0dumpl A/.
```

Will find all files in B, pass them to `cpio` with null termination to properly handle odd file names, create necessary directories (`cpio -d`), preserve ownership, permissions and timestamps (`-m`), and use linking to create the destination files where possible (`-l`) unconditionally (`-u`).